# Are edits described as "Format code" or similar automatically rejected?

Tags: discussion, support, rejected-edits

I [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5524394) to this user's [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269653/jenkins-test-email-notification-in-mac-os-failed) to improve readability by formatting the error trace and configuration block as code, but it was rejected by Community.  Was this an automatic rejection because I described the edit as "Format code"?

I saw [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88627/how-far-can-i-refactor-the-code-in-someone-elses-question) on Stackexchange meta that says that code should not be edited unless it is to format it as code, which is what I thought I was doing.

Is there some mechanism in place to automatically reject edits that appear to reformat code as described above to prevent improper code editing?  Or was I simply wrong in editing the trace output as code to improve readability?

Update:  I see that the original question has now been edited to format the trace as code, but not the configuration (which is formatted with bullet points).  If my edit was not rejected automatically, was it rejected because the configuration should **not** be formatted as code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edits rejected by "Community" normally happen when there are multiple suggested edits at the same time.

It probably means that another edit was made by either the OP or someone else before your edit got approved.

Comment: Yep; see that an edit was made at a similar time (approved ten minutes later, but it could've been in progress in the queue for that long).  Both of you submitted edits at the same time, basically, and his won.  (I would say that his was slightly better, also, though both are fine.)

Comment: Looking at the timestamps it must've been an edit by the OP that triggered the auto-reject. Rejection was at 16:43, well within the grace period active between 16:40 and 16:45.

Comment: There can never be multiple suggested edits, all subsequent ones are blocked at submission if there was none pending at the time the editing was started. Full edits will auto-reject suggested edits as "conflict, by community", and there's "reject and edit" which does a "reject by community" and then an edit by whoever selected that.